# How do I get input element id from placeholder text?

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using Selenium and C#.

I'm trying to find an element id for an input field by the already typed in text (the elements id is autogenerated randomly for every instance) and then type a new text.

My failed attempt:

```
public void SetValues(){
        var textField = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(text(),'my_text')]"));
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver)
            .ExecuteScript("window.scroll(" + textField.Location.X + "," + (textField.Location.Y - 200) + ");");
        textField.sendKeys("some_text");
              }
```

How can I make my code to work?

Answer (score 2):

Place holder is an html attribute so you can use `@placeholder`, check the following line:

```
var textField = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='my_placeholder']"));
```

Edited:
There is no way to get the text entered manually if javascript assigns the value to an attribute.

Comment: What I first thougth was a placeholder is actually a already filled in textfield. I have updated the post. Is there a similar way to find the textfield containing the text "my_text"?

Comment: Simple yet effective answer

Comment: @asasasasas if you type text in a input it is not visible in the HTML code if there is a javascript action after that to assign this value. So it is not possible to get the element by manually added text to input. You may check the HTML code for the text, if you find it there then there should be a way to find it.

Comment: @asasasasas updated the answer, check it. If your case is different you can ask another question or edit the question.